# PHPMailer + HTML5 Interaction

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, phpmailer

So, I downloaded one of those HTML5 free templates, but its PHP contact form cannot work in my server, hence I had to use a PHPMailer to make it work. The thing is that this PHPMailer use an if() to send the form data, if it works it'll show in another window that the message was sent,

```
if(!$mailer->Send()){
   echo "Message not sent";
   echo "Erro: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo; exit; 
                    }
   print "Message sent";
```

but what I do want is that it shows the 'message sent' message on my HTML as it used to do with the previous PHP, and not in another window.

I still had it in my main.js

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),

        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending email...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thanks! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to make it send and use this JSP code instead of its if() + print() function.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to return a chunk of JSON to your request instead of echoing some arbitrary text. You should also check your return value in your jQuery, don't just assume it will work.

Comment: ok, but how @Synchro? do you have some example or sample code?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to even look for yourself, why should we help? Here's [one example](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/) from a trivial search. SO is not a "write my code for me" site.